# Way to convert HTML to Microsoft Word document keeping CSS formating

Tags: microsoft-word, conversion, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make all table borders invisible in MS Word after copying from HTML](https://superuser.com/questions/501688/how-to-make-all-table-borders-invisible-in-ms-word-after-copying-from-html)

I need to convert some reports that are made in HTML and a little bit of CSS (general tags like  and  are used). I tried the good-old copy-paste and just opening with MS Word, but then I stumbled on issues with CSS compatibility, most importantly, table borders.

Is there a (free) converter that could handle table styles?

Comment: Not exactly. These questions differ. In this one I want to see if its possible to keep formatting at all. In the other one I was going for some VBA script or something similar that would remove visibility of borders at all.

Comment: How is that an exact duplicate?